# Reopen recently closed File Explorer window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How can I reopen a recently closed File Explorer window in Windows 10? I sometimes close a File Explorer window by mistake and I want to reopen it, but it is deeply buried in list of folders. It is a pain to reopen it.

I took a look at Windows 10 `Quick Access`. It has frequent folders and recent files, but no recent folders.

[image]

Is there a way to reopen accidentally closed windows explorer? (All internet browsers allow this, so why can't Windows allow this?)

*Note: I am not asking to reopen Internet Browser tab.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are all sorts of recent items in Explorer.

**Recent folders 1**

Previously opened folders in Windows Explorer are available via the little
down arrow to the right of the path information field.

**Recent folders 2**

**A. Make a shortcut**

To make a shortcut to it, right-click on the Desktop, select New > Shortcut,
then enter as location the following string

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}
```

Give it a meaningful name.

**B. Add to Quick access**

Go to one folder short of it in File explorer, so that's
`%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows`,
right-click on `Recent items` and select *Pin to Quick access*.

**Recent items**

This is found in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`
and you may use it in one of the above methods.

**Third-party add-ons to Explorer**

If the above methods are not enough, you need an add-on that might
do better than Microsoft in displaying recent folders.

Here are a couple of such add-ons.
I never used any of them and so cannot recommend one.

- [Chameleon Folder](http://www.chameleon-managers.com/)
  with
  [review](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/20/chameleon-folder-puts-favorite-folders-at-your-fingertips/)
- [Folder Menu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/foldermenu/)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I really appreciate it. I created a 'Recent Folders' shortcut. Unfortunately, it does not keep up with the folders that I close. To test it out, I just opened bunch of folders. Open few files in them. Then closed both files and folders. Then Open `Recent Folders` shortcut from Start. It did not have those folders listed.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following to mitigate that problem:

1. Create a desktop shortcut to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\` and name it **Recent Items**
2. Copy that shortcut to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
3. Right-click the shortcut on the All Apps list and select **Pin to start**
4. Utilize that shortcut and sort by the **Date modified** field

---

Source:  [How Do You Get the “All Recent Files” List Back in Windows 10?](https://www.howtogeek.com/274573/how-do-you-get-the-all-recent-files-list-back-in-windows-10/)

Comment: I tried it, it works good, except, it won't list any files or folders from a shared drive. We have some shared drive for our team, but I can't see those folder shortcuts. Bummer!

Comment: That's rather strange, because it shows those type of items when I navigate to a mapped network drive on my Windows 10 machines here at work.

Answer (score 2):

[Quick Access Popup](https://www.quickaccesspopup.com/) has "Recent Folders" feature, it works with Windows Explorer and other software.

[image: GIF]